# background full screen with 100vh but be bigger if screen is minimized vertically

Tags: html, css, background, screen

I want my background to be full screen with 100vh but i also want it that if I minimize the screen vertically that the background stays at the end of the picture that is on the background

header{background: #efe0d9; display: inline-block;width: 100%; float: left; height:100vh;padding: 1% 0 0;}

I want to have a background that ends at the bottom of the screen becase then the picture that is on the screen is big enough but when I minimize the screen vertically the pictures stay the same size (as wanted) but the background also goes up so the pictures are overlapping with next part of the website[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nESUs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)?

**Edit:** This may not be exactly what you're looking for, since I had to add an extra element, But you could try wrapping the `<header>` in a container with its height set to `100vh`, making the header's contents take up the minimum height you want to cover, and giving the same background color to the wrapper and the header.

Check the snippet and toggle to full screen to see the background expand beyond the header's contents.

```css
#container {
background: #efe0d9;
height: 100vh;
}
header {
  background: #efe0d9;
width: 100%;
}
.stack {
height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
body, p, hr {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<header>
<div class="stack"><hr><p>0px</p></div>
<div class="stack"><hr><p>100px</p></div>
<div class="stack"><hr><p>200px</p></div>
<div class="stack"><hr><p>300px</p></div>
<div class="stack"><hr><p>400px</p></div>
<div class="stack"><hr><p>500px</p></div>
</header>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Adding a container div with its height set to `100vh` and display set to `flex`, and giving the header a `min-height` seems to have done the trick.  [Here's an updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/28w93pb0/)

Comment: @RedSecret I edited my answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: it kinda worked with the 0px 100px ect. but now I dont know how to apply this to my situation

Comment: can I just contact you and share the code with you?

Comment: @RedSecret Copy your code into a jsfiddle and post the link.

Comment: it looks a bit weird because I couldn't add the pictures and video

Comment: @RedSecret Ok, I updated your fiddle (and my answer). I commented out a few lines of your CSS and marked any new lines I added so you should be able to see what I changed pretty easily.

Comment: i'm sorry but I don't see any changes.

Comment: @RedSecret In that updated fiddle, if you expand the result panel vertically, you'll see the header covers the entire height of the panel. But if you reduce it down to less than 500px in height, the header doesn't stop at the bottom of the panel. It will still be at least 500px in height.

Comment: @RedSecret Here it is again with an image. https://jsfiddle.net/bxwg06oh/